# How to add support for additional coding languages?

Tags: release-juno, code

When working on web dev projects, we work with many file formats, some of which aren't recognised by Code, such as *.twig*.

Is there a way to add support for these?

If not, is there a way to treat all files with that extension as a particular language (eg. HTML)?

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know

You should ask in their Github page

https://github.com/elementary/code/issues

Maybe ask for this new feature or some info on where to write the syntax definition...

---

### UPDATE

(time:1543427125)

Thanks for the downvote, you made me learn a new thing. I followed my own suggestion and went to their Github page (as I said could be the best way to get an answer) and looked for people asking for new language support. Normal stuff right?. Found a post of a person asking for "*Language Support for Ren'Py*"

https://github.com/elementary/code/issues/467

There, a person who has the know-how of [code](/questions/tagged/code)'s environment, told him and us that [code](/questions/tagged/code) uses `gtksourceview`

So I went to the old [Google](https://www.google.com/), searched for `"twig gtksourceview"` and found this:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html (I believe this is the Official website of the language?)

If we look for `gtksourceview` we find

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html

,that leads us to:

https://github.com/gabrielcorpse/gedit-twig-template-language

---

### Next

To add support to others just repeat:

1. Go to the official website and look for their gtksourceview template
   format file, if they don't have a template made, look for it in [Google](https://www.google.com/) and if all goes wrong you just can edit/create one yourself. (see below for format definition)
2. Create it or download it
3. Save it in your system where it should (see below)
4. Profit

---

### Where to save it?

User

`~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/`

System-wide

`/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/`

Format

https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html

Comment: So to clarify, we're looking for a `[languagename].lang` file? Thanks for investigating this!

Comment: Not exactly `[languagename].lang`. But in some cases it may be that way. Just explore that directory and there you can find the HTML file in case you don't any solution for the other types you talked so you can copy that or add the extension.